# C# Struct instance behavior changes when captured in lambda

Tags: c#, struct

I've got a work around for this issue, but I'm trying to figure out why it works . Basically, I'm looping through a list of structs using foreach. If I include a LINQ statement that references the current struct before I call a method of the struct, the method is unable to modify the members of the struct. This happens regardless of whether the LINQ statement is even called. I was able to work around this by assigning the value I was looking for to a variable and using that in the LINQ, but I would like to know what is causing this. Here's an example I created.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WeirdnessExample
{
    public struct RawData
    {
        private int id;

        public int ID
        {
            get{ return id;}
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public void AssignID(int newID)
        {
            id = newID;
        }
    }

    public class ProcessedData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ProcessedData> processedRecords = new List<ProcessedData>();
            processedRecords.Add(new ProcessedData()
            {
                ID = 1
            });


            List<RawData> rawRecords = new List<RawData>();
            rawRecords.Add(new RawData()
            {
                ID = 2
            });


            int i = 0;
            foreach (RawData rawRec in rawRecords)
            {
                int id = rawRec.ID;
                if (i < 0 || i > 20)
                {
                    List<ProcessedData> matchingRecs = processedRecords.FindAll(mr => mr.ID == rawRec.ID);
                }

                Console.Write(String.Format("With LINQ: ID Before Assignment = {0}, ", rawRec.ID)); //2
                rawRec.AssignID(id + 8);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ID After Assignment = {0}", rawRec.ID)); //2
                i++;
            }

            rawRecords = new List<RawData>();
            rawRecords.Add(new RawData()
            {
                ID = 2
            });

            i = 0;
            foreach (RawData rawRec in rawRecords)
            {
                int id = rawRec.ID;
                if (i < 0)
                {
                    List<ProcessedData> matchingRecs = processedRecords.FindAll(mr => mr.ID == id);
                }
                Console.Write(String.Format("With LINQ: ID Before Assignment = {0}, ", rawRec.ID)); //2
                rawRec.AssignID(id + 8);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ID After Assignment = {0}", rawRec.ID)); //10
                i++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your example is trying to show. I strongly suspect this is just another example of why mutable structs are a really bad idea.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand it. I'm trying to reproduce this in a much simpler form.

Comment: Note that nothing in your code uses LINQ at all. You're using List.FindAll, which was present in .NET 2.0, and a lambda expression - which are often used *with* LINQ, but aren't really part of LINQ. This is part of what threw me off to start with - I was trying to find anything LINQ-related...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to reproduce this with a rather simpler test program, as shown below, and I now understand it. Admittedly understanding it doesn't make me feel any less nauseous, but hey... Explanation after code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

struct MutableStruct
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public void AssignValue(int newValue)
    {
        Value = newValue;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<MutableStruct>()
        {
            new MutableStruct { Value = 10 }
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Without loop variable capture");
        foreach (MutableStruct item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", item.Value); // 10
            item.AssignValue(30);
            Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", item.Value);  // 30
        }
        // Reset...
        list[0] = new MutableStruct { Value = 10 };

        Console.WriteLine("With loop variable capture");
        foreach (MutableStruct item in list)
        {
            Action capture = () => Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", item.Value);  // 10
            item.AssignValue(30);
            Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", item.Value);   // Still 10!
        }
    }
}
```

The difference between the two loops is that in the second one, the loop variable is *captured* by a lambda expression. The second loop is effectively turned into something like this:

```
// Nested class, would actually have an unspeakable name
class CaptureHelper
{
    public MutableStruct item;

    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
    }
}

...
// Second loop in main method
foreach (MutableStruct item in list)
{
    CaptureHelper helper = new CaptureHelper();
    helper.item = item;
    Action capture = helper.Execute;

    MutableStruct tmp = helper.item;
    Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", tmp.Value);

    tmp = helper.item;
    tmp.AssignValue(30);

    tmp = helper.item;
    Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", tmp.Value);
}
```

Now of course each time we copy the variable out of `helper` we get a fresh copy of the struct. This should normally be fine - the iteration variable is read-only, so we'd *expect* it not to change. However, you have a *method* which changes the contents of the struct, causing the unexpected behaviour.

Note that if you tried to change the *property*, you'd get a compile-time error:

```
Test.cs(37,13): error CS1654: Cannot modify members of 'item' because it is a
    'foreach iteration variable'
```

Lessons:

- Mutable structs are evil
- Structs which are mutated by *methods* are doubly evil
- Mutating a struct via a method call on an iteration variable which has been captured is triply evil to the extent of breakage

It's not 100% clear to me whether the C# compiler is behaving as per the spec here. I suspect it is. Even if it's not, I wouldn't want to suggest the team should put any effort into fixing it. Code like this is just *begging* to be broken in subtle ways.

Comment: And if we add interfaces to the mix, nasal demons!

Comment: @leppie: The trouble is, part of me immediately starts wondering how I can abuse this to best effect...

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. It took me a while to realize that the programmer that did this was modifying a mutable struct. When I added in the LINQ it just stopped working. Really confusing.

Comment: @user1097991: As per my comment on the question, there's no LINQ involved here. There's a lambda expression, but that's not LINQ.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I would say that issue not in lambda expression per se but in different treatment of the loop variable based on loop body (actually in treatment of what read-only local variable means).

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov: Well, based on whether the loop body contains an anonymous function (lambda expression or anonymous method) which captures the iteration variable.

Comment: If one changes changes the signature of `AssignId` to `public static void AssignID(ref RawData it, int newID)`, what happens?  If `item` is supposed to be read-only, I would expect that using the alternate function (passing `item` by `ref`) would cause the compiler to correctly squawk in both cases.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, that fails to compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I wish there was a way to indicate whether or not particular methods or properties should be usable on struct instances that cannot legally be passed as `ref`, since 99% of "mutable struct problems" occur with code which would cause a compiler squawk if such feature existed, and because there are times when it would be useful to allow property setters to be invoked on certain "read-only" structures [e.g. it would be useful for `ArraySegment` to allow read-write indexed property access to the array, but many languages won't allow any property setters to be used on read-only structs].

Comment: This is clearly a bug. If it's in the spec, then it's a spec bug, but still a bug.

Comment: @luiscubal: It would at least be a design flaw. In fact it *is* a compiler bug (confirmed).

Comment: Fascinating! <raises one eyebrow>. It made a good episode on TekPub TV, too. Just for fun, I rewrote Jon's example as an MSpec test. http://www.tigranetworks.co.uk/blogs/electricdreams/the-evil-of-mutable-structs/

Answer (score 4):

Ok. We definitely have an issues here but I suspect that this issue not with closures per se  but with foreach implementation instead.

C# 4.0 specification stated (8.8.4 The foreach statement) that "the iteration variable corresponds to a **read-only local variable** with a scope that extends over the embedded statement". That's why we can't change loop variable or increment it's property (as Jon already stated):

```
struct Mutable
{
    public int X {get; set;}
    public void ChangeX(int x) { X = x; }
}

var mutables = new List<Mutable>{new Mutable{ X = 1 }};
foreach(var item in mutables)
{
  // Illegal!
  item = new Mutable(); 

  // Illegal as well!
  item.X++;
}
```

In this regard read-only loop variables behave almost exactly the same as any readonly field (in terms of accessing this variable outside of the constructor):

- We can't change readonly field outside of the constructor
- We can't change property of the read-only field of value type
- We're treating readonly fields as values that leads to using a temporary copy every time we accessing readonly field of value type.

.

```
class MutableReadonly
{
  public readonly Mutable M = new Mutable {X = 1};
}

// Somewhere in the code
var mr = new MutableReadonly();

// Illegal!
mr.M = new Mutable();

// Illegal as well!
mr.M.X++;

// Legal but lead to undesired behavior
// becaues mr.M.X remains unchanged!
mr.M.ChangeX(10);
```

There is a plenty of issues related to mutable value types and one of them related to the last behavior: changing readonly struct via mutator method (like `ChangeX`) lead to obscure behavior because we'll **modify a copy** but not an readonly object itself:

```
mr.M.ChangeX(10);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var tmp = mr.M;
tmp.ChangeX(10);
```

If loop variable treated by the C# compiler as a read-only local variable, than its seems reasonable to expect the same behavior for them as for read-only fields.

Right now loop variable in the simple loop (without any closures) behaves almost the same as a read-only field except copying it for every access. But if code changes and closure comes to play, loop variable starts behaving like pure read-only variable:

```
var mutables = new List<Mutable> { new Mutable { X = 1 } };

foreach (var m in mutables)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before change: {0}", m.X); // X = 1

    // We'll change loop variable directly without temporary variable
    m.ChangeX(10);

    Console.WriteLine("After change: {0}", m.X); // X = 10
}

foreach (var m in mutables)
{
    // We start treating m as a pure read-only variable!
    Action a = () => Console.WriteLine(m.X));

    Console.WriteLine("Before change: {0}", m.X); // X = 1

    // We'll change a COPY instead of a m variable!
    m.ChangeX(10);

    Console.WriteLine("After change: {0}", m.X); // X = 1
}
```

Unfortunately I can't find strict rules how read-only local variables should behave but its clear that this behavior is different based on loop body: we're not copying to locals for every access in simple loop, but we DO this if the loop body closes over loop variable.

We all know that [Closing over loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) and that loop implementation was changed in the C# 5.0. Simple way to fix that old issue in pre C# 5.0 era was introducing local variable, but interesting that introducing local variable in this our case will change behavior as well:

```
foreach (var mLoop in mutables)
{
    // Introducing local variable!
    var m = mLoop;

    // We're capturing local variable instead of loop variable
    Action a = () => Console.WriteLine(m.X));

    Console.WriteLine("Before change: {0}", m.X); // X = 1

    // We'll roll back this behavior and will change
    // value type directly in the closure without making a copy!
    m.ChangeX(10); // X = 10 !!

    Console.WriteLine("After change: {0}", m.X); // X = 1
}
```

Actually this means that C# 5.0 has very subtle breaking change because no one will introduce a local variable any more (and even tools like ReSharper stops warning about it in VS2012 because its not an issue).

I'm OK with both behaviors but inconsistency seems strange.

Comment: I wonder if there would be any difficulty with Microsoft adding a attribute that struct methods and properties could use to indicate whether they modify the underlying structure, so that compilers could forbid the calling of `this`-mutating method and properties on read-only structures but permit it on properties (including setters) that do not modify `this` [an example of the latter would be a version of `ArraySegment` that allowed read-write indexed access to the underlying array].

Comment: Does the change in C# 5.0 changes the behaviour described in the original question?

Comment: No, it's not. But it can hide it even deeper, because in c# 5 no one will introduce local variable for capturing loop variable.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this has to do with how lambda expressions are evaluated.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898925/is-there-a-reason-for-cs-reuse-of-the-variable-in-a-foreach) and its answer for more details.

Question:

> When using lambda expressions or anonymous methods in C#, we have to be wary of the access to modified closure pitfall. For example:
>
> ```
> foreach (var s in strings)
> {
>    query = query.Where(i => i.Prop == s); // access to modified closure
> ```
>
> Due to the modified closure, the above code will cause all of the Where clauses on the query to be based on the final value of `s`.

Answer:

> This is one of the worst "gotchas" in C#, and **we are going to take the breaking change to fix it.** In C# 5 the foreach loop variable will be logically inside the body of the loop, and therefore closures will get a fresh copy every time.

Comment: I think it *is* to do with the lambda expression, but not in quite the way that you're expecting. It's *not* fixed in C# 5 though - I'm using the C# 5 compiler now, and still seeing the same behaviour.

Comment: @JonSkeet - That wouldn't surprise me.  Nothing I've seen on closure before has specifically addressed structs, so I took an educated guess.  I didn't actually test it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just to accomplish Sergey's post, I wanna to add following example with manual closure, that demonstrates compiler's behavior. Of course compiler might have any other implementation that satisfies **readonly** requirement of **captured within foreach** statement variable.

```
static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<MutableStruct>()
    {
        new MutableStruct { Value = 10 }
    };

    foreach (MutableStruct item in list)
    {
       var c = new Closure(item);

       Console.WriteLine(c.Item.Value);
       Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", c.Item.Value);  // 10
       c.Item.AssignValue(30);
       Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", c.Item.Value);   // Still 10!
    }
}

class Closure
{
    public Closure(MutableStruct item){
    Item = item;
}
    //readonly modifier is mandatory
    public readonly MutableStruct Item;
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Item.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your issue. It swaps out `foreach` for a `for` and makes the `struct` immutable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WeirdnessExample
{
    public struct RawData
    {
        private readonly int id;

        public int ID
        {
            get{ return id;}
        }

        public RawData(int newID)
        {
            id = newID;
        }
    }

    public class ProcessedData
    {
        private readonly int id;

        public int ID
        {
            get{ return id;}
        }

        public ProcessedData(int newID)
        {
            id = newID;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ProcessedData> processedRecords = new List<ProcessedData>();
            processedRecords.Add(new ProcessedData(1));


            List<RawData> rawRecords = new List<RawData>();
            rawRecords.Add(new RawData(2));


            for (int i = 0; i < rawRecords.Count; i++)
            {
                RawData rawRec = rawRecords[i];
                int id = rawRec.ID;
                if (i < 0 || i > 20)
                {
                    RawData rawRec2 = rawRec;
                    List<ProcessedData> matchingRecs = processedRecords.FindAll(mr => mr.ID == rawRec2.ID);
                }

                Console.Write(String.Format("With LINQ: ID Before Assignment = {0}, ", rawRec.ID)); //2
                rawRec = new RawData(rawRec.ID + 8);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ID After Assignment = {0}", rawRec.ID)); //2
                i++;
            }

            rawRecords = new List<RawData>();
            rawRecords.Add(new RawData(2));

            for (int i = 0; i < rawRecords.Count; i++)
            {
                RawData rawRec = rawRecords[i];
                int id = rawRec.ID;
                if (i < 0)
                {
                    List<ProcessedData> matchingRecs = processedRecords.FindAll(mr => mr.ID == id);
                }
                Console.Write(String.Format("With LINQ: ID Before Assignment = {0}, ", rawRec.ID)); //2
                rawRec = new RawData(rawRec.ID + 8);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ID After Assignment = {0}", rawRec.ID)); //10
                i++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```